# The database in recovery

Tags: sql-server, restore

I use a database named BI, every night it is restored. It worked great but since some days ago it is shown that the database is in recover. I used

```
RESTORE <BI> WITH RECOVERY
```

but it gives me

```
RESTORE cannot operate on database 'BI' because it is configured for database mirroring or has joined an availability group. If you intend to restore the database, use ALTER DATABASE to remove mirroring or to remove the database from its availability group.
```

does anybody has other ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody has other ideas to solve this problem?

Do as error message says, perhaps you connected wrong SQL Instance this time.

Using following query, you can verify whether the database part of AG or not:

```
select name, IIF(group_database_id IS NULL, 'NO', 'YES') is_joined_AG 
from sys.databases;

select DB_NAME (database_id) mirrored_db
from sys.database_mirroring
where mirroring_guid is not null;
```

Comment: thank you, this is the output  [name]=BI [is_joined_AG] = No
                                           ,So     how I can fix it?

Comment: @Zahra, Ok, something unclear on the question, can you pls include the details i.e. Environment (version, DEV/UAT/PROD) and steps that you have tried. BTW, as the error indicate and in fact, the database that you trying to restore is part of AG or Mirroring, and it's impossible to do RESTORE unless the DB removed from AG and Mirroring.